# Manage the parent toggle case

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, accordion

I had built a structure parent and child using accordion. 
Structure of my view is something like below. When I click on any child 
so I clone the parent and then  I move the child element to the right side.

```
parent1           
 child1
 child2
 child3
parent2
 child1
 child2
```

Suppose I click on child1 So

```
Left-hand side                         Right Hand Side
parent1                                parent1                                                                        
                                        child1
 child2
 child3
parent2
 child1
 child2
```

Why am I doing cloning? Because I want the parent should be there on the left-hand side. Only the child element I am moving to the right-hand side.
Accordion provides collapsable and expands feature when you click. In my case, I have added that feature to my parent. Whenever user will click on the parent the child element will get expanded. And if click on the parent again it will get collapse.

**My PROBLEM IS** when I click on suppose parent1 so it will get expand but on the right-hand side where I am cloning the parent, it will also get expand . Also If I collapse my parent on left-hand side it will affect the right-hand side parent. So I want to differentiate between left-hand side and right-hand side parent. But the thing is accordion just provides active class only. So can anyone give me some direction how to solve this problem

```
<dl id="available_fields_container" class="accordion list_container ui-sortable active" data-accordion="one">
  <dd class="accordion-navigation active" id="data_download_fields">
    <a href="#data_download_fields">
      <b>FootBall Fields</b>
      <span class="collapse-symbol"></span>
    </a>
    <span class="select-group" data-fields="#data_download_fields">Select all</span>
    <div id="data_download_fields" class="content active" data-group="FootBall Fields">

      <div class="field_items"  data-index="4" data-group="FootBall Fields">
        Andrew
        <span class="plus-icon action-icon">+</span>
        <i class="icon-cross2 action-icon"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="field_items"  data-index="5" data-group="FootBall Fields">
        Sam
        <span class="plus-icon action-icon">+</span>
        <i class="icon-cross2 action-icon"></i>
      </div>

    </div>
  </dd>

    <dd class="accordion-navigation " id="data_download_hockey_fields">
      <a href="#data_download_hockey_fields">
        <b>hockey Fields</b>
        <span class="collapse-symbol"></span>
      </a>
      <span class="select-group" data-fields="#data_download_hockey_fields">Select all</span>
      <div id="data_download_hockey_fields" class="content " data-group="hockey Fields">
          <div class="field_items"  data-index="0" data-group="hockey Fields">
  jason
    <span class="plus-icon action-icon">+</span>
    <i class="icon-cross2 action-icon"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="field_items"  data-index="1" data-group="hockey Fields">
  Jane
    <span class="plus-icon action-icon">+</span>
    <i class="icon-cross2 action-icon"></i>
  </div>

      </div>
    </dd>

</dl>
```

Comment: please share a bit of your example in https://jsfiddle.net/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the default toggle functionality provided by accordion

```
$(document).foundation({
    accordion: {
      content_class: false,
      active_class: false
    },
  });
```

Now you just need to add and remove a class on the parent

```
$( document ).on('click','.field_items' , function() {
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('active')){
      $(this).parent().removeClass( "active" )
      $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("active")
    }
  });

  $( document ).on('click','#available_fields_container > dd.accordion-navigation' , function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("active")){
      $(this).removeClass( "active" )
      $(this).find('.content').removeClass('active')
    }else{
      $(this).addClass( "active")
      $(this).find('.content').addClass('active')
    }
  });
```